# Spring Security "Remember Me" redirection to login

Tags: spring, primefaces, spring-security, remember-me

I'm trying to implement remember me functionallity in my webapp with Spring Security. The cookie is established correctly (I've seen it in browser) and recognized by the server (my app finds the user in bbdd) but always I am being redirected to login page. Does Anybody can help me?

My Security configuration is:

```
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;
RememberMeAuthenticationProvider rememberMeAuthenticationProvider = new RememberMeAuthenticationProvider(
        "OTRS_KEY");

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.debug(true)
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/unsec/**", "/resources/**", "/css/**",
                    "/images/**", "/design/**", "/javax.faces.resource/**",
                    "/syntaxhighlighter/**");
}

/*
 * JSF 1.2/2.0/2.1/2.2 has implicit CSRF protection when h:form is submitted
 * with a POST request. This is because the javax.faces.ViewState hidden
 * field contains a sufficiently random token. JSF 2.2 adds CSRF protection
 * to HTTP GET by allowing the developer to specify protected-views in the
 * WEB-INF/faces-config.xml descriptor. URLs that invoke the JSF lifecycle
 * via HTTP GET must have the new javax.faces.Token URL parameter. For more
 * information, see the tutorial titled Java EE 7: Implementing CSRF
 * Protection with JSF 2.2.
 */
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().headers().frameOptions().disable().formLogin()
            .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
            .usernameParameter("j_username")
            .passwordParameter("j_password")
            .loginPage("/unsec/secureLogin.jsf")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/sec/home.jsf")
            .failureUrl("/unsec/secureLogin.jsf").and().rememberMe()
            .rememberMeServices(tokenBasedRememberMeServices()).and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/unsec/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/sec/**").authenticated().and().logout()
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID", "OTRS_REMEMBER");

}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    // return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
}

private TokenBasedRememberMeServices tokenBasedRememberMeServices() {
    TokenBasedRememberMeServices t = new TokenBasedRememberMeServices(
            "OTRS_KEY", satecAuthenticationProvider.getIdentitiesService());
    t.setParameter("_spring_security_remember_me_input");
    t.setAlwaysRemember(true);
    t.setCookieName("OTRS_REMEMBER");
    t.setTokenValiditySeconds(7200);
    return t;
}
```

}

Comment: How is this PrimeFaces related? (other then 'Im using it')

Comment: Because Spring security filters acts over Primefaces and JSF lifecycle